# How do I "collapse all" folds using Perl EPIC

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I see there's an option to set the hot keys for "Collapse All" in the Eclipse Preferences, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  The only way I can get code to fold, other than manually, is by setting code folding to take place when the file is loaded.  Anytime after that I have to fold them manually.

I'm looking for something similar to Visual Studio's CTRL+M+O.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. The shortcut key doesn't work for EPIC, even with the latest release.

It is an known open issue http://sourceforge.net/p/e-p-i-c/bugs/620/

Answer (score 0):

a year and a half and this is still an issue.  Has work stopped on EPIC?